# How is Harish-Chandra restriction compatible with Harish-Chandra series?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a connected reductive group over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$, with Frobenius $F$. Let $(L_0,\Lambda_0)$ be a cuspidal pair with $L_0$ a Levi subgroup of a Levi subgroup $L$, and let ${^{\ast}{R^G_L}}$ denote the Harish-Chandra restriction functor. Supposedly, if $M$ is in the Harish-Chandra series for $G^F$ with respect to $(L_0,\Lambda_0)$, i.e., $M$ is a simple $G^F$-module and there is a surjection $R^G_{L_0}(\Lambda_0)\to M$, then any simple submodule of ${^\ast R^G_L(M)}$ is in the Harish-Chandra series for $L^F$ with respect to $(L_0,\Lambda_0)$.

How does one see this? If you have a simple submodule $N\to {^\ast R^G_L(M)}$, and a surjection $R^G_{L_0}(\Lambda_0)\to M$, how can you construct a surjection $R^L_{L_0}(\Lambda_0)\to N$?

Exploiting exactness, transitivity, and the adjunction yields maps like an injection $\Lambda_0\to {^\ast R^G_{L_0}(M)}$, a surjection $R^G_L(N)\to M$, and at least some nonzero morphism $R^L_{L_0}(\Lambda_0)\to {^\ast R^G_L(M)}$, but I don't see a way to piece these together to get the desired surjection.

Comment: Everything's complex, right?  In that setting, we're dealing with semisimple representations, so the difference between simple submodule and simple quotient module doesn't matter.  Thus $N$ is a simple submodule of ${^*R^G_L}(R_{L_0}^G(\Lambda_0))$, i.e., $R_L^G(N)$ and $R_{L_0}^G(\Lambda_0)$ intertwine.  If $N$ is in the Harish-Chandra series of $(L_0', \Lambda_0')$, then that means that $R_{L_0'}^G(\Lambda_0')$ and $R_{L_0}^G(\Lambda_0)$ intertwine, so that $(L_0, \Lambda_0)$ is conjugate to $(L_0', \Lambda_0')$.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, everything can be assumed to be complex. So assuming instead the existence of a surjection  ${^{\ast}{R^G_L}(M)}\to N$, one gets a surjection ${^{\ast}{R^G_L}}(R^G_{L_0}(\Lambda_0))\to {^\ast{R^G_L(M)}}\to N$, so there is a nonzero morphism $R^G_{L_0}(\Lambda_0)\to R^G_L(N)$. Is that what you mean be intertwine? I've not heard this word in this context.

Comment: And what is $(L_0',\Lambda_0')$ in what follows? I don't understand why $N$ is in the HC series for $L$ with respect to $(L_0,\Lambda_0)$, so I don't understand why this new cuspidal pair is being introduced.

Comment: By saying that two representations intertwine, I mean that there is a non-$0$ morphism from one to the other.  In the complex unitary setting, this is a symmetric relation, and is equivalent to their having a common simple submodule or a common simple quotient.  A priori we don't know that $N$ is in the HC series for $(L_0, \Lambda_0)$, but it is in *some* HC series; so I just give a name to that series, and then show *a posteriori* that it is conjugate to $(L_0, \Lambda_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\Ind[3]{R_{#1}^{#2}(#3)}\newcommand\Res[3]{{^*R^{#1}_{#2}(#3)}}\DeclareMathOperator\Int{Int}\DeclareMathOperator\Norm{Norm}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$This is not literally true as stated.  For example, if $L = L_0 = A$ is a split maximal torus in, say, $G = \operatorname{SL}_2$, and if $\Lambda_0$ is any non-quadratic character of $L_0^F$ (i.e., $\Lambda_0^2 \ne 1$), then $M = \Ind{L_0}G{\Lambda_0}$ is irreducible, but $\Res G L M$ admits the Weyl conjugate $(L_0, \Lambda_0^{-1})$ of $(L_0, \Lambda_0)$ as quotient.

Based on the notation, I think you are using [Digne and Michel - Representations of finite groups of Lie type](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/representations-of-finite-groups-of-lie-type/9B062C00D7D41F67B0948890A09EFD84).  I will cite from there.

What is true is that, in your setting, there is some $g \in G^F$ such that $N$ lies in the Harish-Chandra series of $(\Int(g)L_0, \Lambda_0 \circ \Int(g)^{-1})$.  I argue as in my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360559/how-is-harish-chandra-restriction-compatible-with-harish-chandra-series#comment908341_360559).  Namely, since all representations are unitary, two representations admit a non-$0$ intertwining map (either way) if and only if they share a composition factor, and all (simple) composition factors are both submodules and quotient modules (Lemma 5.3.6).  Because of the symmetry, I will just say that two representations intertwine if there is a non-$0$ intertwining map between them (in either direction).  Thus $M$ is a submodule of $\Ind{L_0}G{\Lambda_0}$, so that $N$ is a submodule of $\Res G L{\Ind{L_0}G{\Lambda_0}}$.  On the other hand, by Theorem 5.3.7, there is *some* cuspidal pair $(L_0', \Lambda_0')$ in $L$ such that $N$ is a quotient, hence a submodule, of $\Ind{L_0'}L{\Lambda_0'}$.  Thus $\Res G L{\Ind{L_0}G{\Lambda_0}}$ and $\Ind{L_0'}L{\Lambda_0'}$ share a simple submodule, hence intertwine; so, by Frobenius reciprocity (Proposition 5.1.3), using transitivity (Proposition 5.1.4(i)), there is also a non-$0$ intertwining map $\Ind{L_0'}G{\Lambda_0'} = \Ind L G{\Ind{L_0'}L{\Lambda_0'}} \to \Ind{L_0}G{\Lambda_0}$.  Now the desired fact follows from another application of Theorem 5.3.7.

(I have edited the previous paragraph to correct the typo ($N$ for $\Lambda_0'$) @AdelaideDokras [pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360559/how-is-harish-chandra-restriction-compatible-with-harish-chandra-series/360600#comment908522_360600).)

Incidentally, in the $p$-adic setting with which I am more familiar, the cuspidal pair to whose Harish-Chandra series a representation belongs is called its *cuspidal support*; Harish-Chandra induction and restriction are usually called parabolic induction and Jacquet restriction, respectively; and both depend, at the level of *representations* (rather than of the Grothendieck group), on a choice of parabolic, not just of Levi.  See [Casselman's $p$-adic notes](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/p-adic-book.pdf) for an excellent reference.  In that setting, we see that, though the individual representations are different, all choices of parabolic yield the same semisimplified representation (i.e., have the same composition factors, counted with multiplicity) (Theorem 6.3.11).  In that setting, one has to replace my free-wheeling disregard of the difference between simple submodules and quotient submodules with the convenient fact that one can 'move' any composition factor of the parabolic induction down to the bottom of the composition series (i.e., realise it as a submodule), possibly by choosing a different parabolic with the same Levi component (Corollary 6.3.7).  (The irreducibility result I quote above is Theorem 6.6.1.)  Then the corrected result above is Theorem 6.3.6.

Comment: I'm trying to write it for myself to see if I've understood correctly: If $(L'_0,\Lambda'_0)$ is a cuspidal pair in $L$ such that $N$ is in the HC-series, then $N$ is a quotient/submodule of $R^L_{L'_0}(\Lambda'_0)$ yes? Not $R^L_{L'_0}(N)$? Then I understand that via reciprocity and transitivity, there is a nonzero intertwining map $R^G_{L'_0}(\Lambda'_0)=R^G_L(R^L_{L'_0}(\Lambda'_0))\to R^G_{L_0}(\Lambda_0)$. Thus $(L'_0,\Lambda'_0)=(L_0,\Lambda_0)^g$ for some $g\in G^F$. Then $R^L_{L_0^g}(\Lambda_0^g)=R^L_{L'_0}(\Lambda'_0)$, that latter of which contains $N$ as a submodule/quotient.

Comment: And the former is isomorphic to $R^L_{L_0}(\Lambda_0)$, so $N$ is in the HC series of $L$ with respect to $(L_0,\Lambda_0)$. I'm just concerned since $g$ need not normalize $L^F$.

Comment: You are right that I meant $\Lambda_0'$, not $N$, whenever inducing off $L_0'$.  It is not clear to me, and not true in general as indicated in my first paragraph, why $R_{\operatorname{Int}(g)L_0}^L(\Lambda_0 \circ \operatorname{Int}(g)^{-1})$ should be isomorphic to $R_{L_0}^L(\Lambda_0)$ (since the conjugacy is happening inside $G^F$, not $L^F$).

Comment: In fact, a natural question is whether $g$ can be chosen inside $\operatorname{Norm}_{G^F}(L)$, not just $G^F$.  I suspect so, but I couldn't prove it (but even this wouldn't give the result claimed in your original post, which is false).

Comment: Thanks again. I had the same concern that $g$ needs to normalize $L^F$. I know the additions to the 2nd edition of Digne-Michel are based off some joint notes by Dudas and Michel, where originally the compatibility of the HC series is only mentioned for HC induction, not restriction. That direction is much easier to understand. I think I'll just keep in mind your counterpoints to the statement, instead of fully accepting what is written in the book for now.